# finding all the roots (including complex)of the equation

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all the roots of $z^4=16(z+2i)^4$.

Can someone help me teach/ guide to solve this equation?

Comment: There are lots of 4-th powers everywhere.  Try taking 4-th roots of both sides.  But remember what you have to do when taking a square root of a equation?  That you get a $\pm 1$ term (in other words, two potential answers)?  What should happen by taking 4-th roots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the square root of both sides. Then affix with +/- to get 2 cases for that equation. Then for each case, get the square root again. Then affix the resulting equation with +/- to get 4 cases. Finally, solve for z for each of the 4 equations.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint* : $z=2u(z+2i)$ , where $u=\{\pm1,\pm i\}$

Comment: The OP did not ask for answers, but some guidance

Comment: Too explicit, or too vague ?

Comment: The OP could have got the answer from WolframAlpha. I think you need to explain step by step how you reached these answeres. I have not solved it myself though.

Comment: There's nothing to ‘solve’, that's the whole point; all one has to do is to directly extract the fourth-root, with the mention that the four [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity) also include $-1$, as well as $\pm i$.

Comment: Yeah. Precisely. I did not even gaze at the question long enough.

Comment: I think @aaa answer does precisely what OP wants.